# ¿Como puedo redefinir el método isEnabled() en java?

Tags: java, java-swing, eclipse, java-8

estoy creando un componente el cual extiende de JTextArea, este re define el método setEnabled(), el cual solo setea si el componente es editable o no. El problema es que quiero re definir el método isEnabled() en el componente para que retorne un boolean si el componente esta enabled o no, ya que al re definir el método setEnabled() este no se comporta de manera correcta. Al re definir el método isEnebled() retornando la bandera esEnabled, el método setEnabled() que re definir deja de comportarse correctamente.

```
public class TextArea extends JTextArea {
    private boolean esEnabled;
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public TextArea() {
        super();
        esEnabled = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabled(boolean b) {
        this.setEditable(b);
        esEnabled = b;
    }
    public boolean esEnabled() {
        return esEnabled;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es asegurarte que la lógica del componente padre sea invocada, usando *super*

```
public class TextArea extends JTextArea {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public TextArea() {
    super();
    this.setEnabled(false);
  }

  @Override
  public void setEnabled(boolean b) {
    super.setEnabled(b);
    this.setEditable(b);
  }

  // ¿Por qué existe este método? Usa directamente isEnabled
  public boolean esEnabled() {
    return isEnabled();
  }
}
```

En todo caso no entiendo muy bien que quieres hacer, porque que yo sepa los componentes desactivados no son editables, y redefinir el contrato de las superclases/interfaces puede ser delicado.

Comment: NOTA: ¿Puede ser que simplemente no te hayas dado cuenta que *esEnabled* NO REEMPLAZA *isEnabled*?

Comment: Estimado @SJuan76 , una pregunta ¿que es el contrato superclase/interfaces, si no usa interfaces el programa?

Comment: lo que yo necesito es que al llamar a setEnabled() solo me modifique el isEditable, esto es porque estoy trabajando con paneles y tengo un metodo que recorre todos los componenetes del JPanel y llama al setEnabled() y al cambo JTextArea al setearlo como enabled false las letras quedan muy claritas y no se puede leer con claridad. Esta funcionalidad esta bien definida. El problema esta que yo quiero re definir a isCambio para que me devuelva el boolean que mencione,  y cuando lo redefino deja de andar el setEnabled, por eso cree el metodo esEnabled(). ¿Me explico?

Comment: Al implementar una interfaz o extender una clase, tu código debería cumplir con el funcionamiento específicado en la interfaz o clase. Si llamas a *setEnabled* pero no te deshabilita el componente, tu código posiblemente no está cumpliendo el contrato, mientras que el programa que usa tu componente espera que sí se esté cumpliendo (porque al fin y al cabo, para ese código el objeto es un *JTextArea*). Y eso causa problemas.